# ¿Cómo solucionar Cannot access offset of type string on string?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un foreach el cual está recorriendo un arreglo, cuando pasa por la primer iteración todo sale normal, pero cuando llega a su segunda iteración de foreach me salta el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
foreach ($valorPregunta['opciones'] as $key => $value) {
    $num = $value['numeroOpcion'];
}
```

Y el error se genera en la línea $num = $value['numeroOpcion'];

EXTRA: Por si es de interés, el arreglo principal, es un arreglo que almacena otros 3 arreglos dentro de él.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada, gracias por tomarte un tiempo para responderme. Sobre lo que me dices, lo he intentado y de echo lo acabo de intentar nuevamente ya que me dijiste, y ahora el error que salta es: Attempt to read property "opciones" on array

Comment: En principio tendrías que condicionar que el elemento no sea el que tiene la clave `esCorrecta`, pues ese tiene un string como valor en vez de un array . Algo así `if($key !== 'esCorrecta') $num = $value['numeroOpcion'];`.

Comment: Muy cierto, olvidé programar esa condición, ha funcionado a partir de condicionar esa parte, muchas gracias.